# python access denied while computing c drive size

Tags: python, directory, filesize, access-denied

I'm using the following function to compute the size of a directory using Python

```
def get_path_size(path):
    total_size = 0
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            fp = os.path.join(path, f)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)

    return total_size
```

I have tested it with many directories, but it doesn't work when I try to compute the size of the C drive

```
print(get_path_size("C:/"))
```

OSError: [WinError 1920] The system cannot access the file: 'C:/Users\asus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\MicrosoftEdge.exe'

How can I compute a directory's size without having admin rights ?

Comment: A directory is different from a drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the particular case you look for the usage of a drive, I'd suggest you use `shutil`:

```
import shutil
shutil.disk_usage("C:")
```

Yields:

```
usage(total=498439548928, used=204051705856, free=294387843072)
```

Notice that there is a slight discrepancy with the value reported in the GUI, because of reserved space on the drive not taken into account, so it might not be suitable for your need.

Comment: But can I use shutil to compute the size used by any directory ?

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Not really, but your problem comes from the fact that certain files are not accessible without admin privileges, and as mentioned in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize), `getsize` raise an error if _the file is not accessible_. I'm afraid that if you don't have the correct rights, you won't be able to compute the size of a directory